Detail Panel in MUI Data Grid Premium is repeating itself
I am using MUI Data Grid Premium To achieve the following design:

I used 2 model to group the data together. The models used were: accounts and symbols.
Inside the data grid, I used the getDetailPanelContent to render the table inside the modelled data grid.
The problem is that if the models, for example, grouped 3 data sets, then the detail panel is also rendered thrice. I want the detail panels to rendered only irrespective of how many data sets were modelled together.
I am attaching my code below:
The modelled data grid:
import * as React from "react";
import {
  DataGridPremium,
  useGridApiRef,
  useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid-premium";
/* import { useSelector } from '@mui/x-data-grid'; */
import GridFive_Three from "./GridFive_Three";
import gridFive from "./GridFiveData";

import "./GridSix.css";

export default function GridSix() {
  const apiRef = useGridApiRef();

  const initialState = useKeepGroupedColumnsHidden({
    apiRef,
    initialState: {
      rowGrouping: {
        model: ["account" , "symbol"],
      },
      aggregation: {
        model: {
          quantity: "sum",
          filledQuantity: "sum",
          unrealizedPNL: "sum",
          realizedPNL: "sum",
          totalPNL: "sum",
          qtyBought: "sum",
          qtySold: "sum",
          qtyShorted: "sum",
        },
      },
    },
  });

  const getDetailPanelContent = React.useCallback((params) => {
    return <GridFive_Three row={params.row.innerData} />;
  }, []);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    
    console.log(apiRef.current.getRowsCount())

  }, [apiRef.current])
  


  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGridPremium
        apiRef={apiRef}
        columns={gridFive.columns}
        rows={gridFive.rows}
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
        initialState={initialState}
        getAggregationPosition={(groupNode) =>
          groupNode.depth === -1 ? null : "inline"
        }
        getDetailPanelContent={getDetailPanelContent}
        /* slots={{
          columnMenu: GridFive_Three,
        }}
        slotProps={{
          columnMenu: { background: 'red', counter: gridFive.rows.length, row: gridFive.rows.innerData },
        }} */
      />
    </div>
  );
}


The nested table component:
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import {
  DataGridPremium,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid-premium";

export default function GridFive_Three({ row , column }) {
  return (
    <div className="grid-five-three" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <div style={{ height: 350, width: "100%" }}>
        <DataGridPremium
          {...row}
          initialState={{
            rowGrouping: {
              model: [""],
            },
          }}
          disableVirtualization
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


I am getting this output:

I want that the nested table should be rendered once no matter how many data sets are grouped together using the models.
